# Minicom script called from jenkins failing on exit of '! killall -9 minicom'

Tags: bash, jenkins, serial-port, gnu-screen

I managed to make a script which sends a few commands via minicom and stores them on output.txt. The script which calls minicom, is called `dut.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Setting up DUT" 
stm_armv7 -print "DUT"
stm_armv7 -dut
echo "wait 30s"
sleep 30s

stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 115200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
rm /home/fsnk/scripts/serial-com/output.txt
export TERM=linux-c-nc
minicom -b 115200 -D /dev/ttyACM0 -C /home/fsnk/scripts/serial-com/output.txt -S /home/fsnk/scripts/serial-com/serial -o 
echo "wait another 5s"
sleep 5s
stm_armv7 -ts
```

So on `minicom` command, i give another file called just `serial` which has some runscript code.

```
# UNIX login script.
# Can be used to automatically login to almost every UNIX box.
#
# Some variables.
set a 0
set b a
print Trying to Login..
# Skip initial 'send ""', it seems to matter sometimes..
send ""
goto login

login:
if a > 3 goto failed1
expect {
    "ogin:"       send "root"  
    "assword:"    send ""
    timeout 5    goto loop1
   
}
goto loop1

loop1:
send "systemctl is-system-running --wait"
sleep 3
# Send command not more than three times.
inc b
if b > 3 goto failed1
expect {
    "\nrunning"    goto success1
    break
    "degrading"  goto success2        
    break
    timeout 5    goto failed2
   
}

success1:    
print \nSuccessfully received running!
! killall -9 minicom
exit

success2:
print \nSuccessfully received degrading!
! killall -9 minicom
exit

failed1:
print \nConnection Failed (wrong password?)
! killall -9 minicom
exit

failed2: 
print \nMessage sending failed. Didn't receive anything!
! killall -9 minicom
exit
```

The command `! killall -9 minicom` kills the minicom terminal based from its [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/runscript). As i mentioned it earlier, when i run this locally, or when i call the script via ssh from my local machine, it runs okay. The problem occurs when i run this from jenkins.

The output.txt file gets created, but remains empty while on Jenkins, i receive a minicom message like this:

```
Setting up DUT
wait 30s

Welcome to minicom 2.7

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Apr 22 2017, 09:14:19.
Port /dev/ttyACM0, 16:30:57

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

/home/fsnk/scripts/serial-com/dut.sh: line 12:  5639 Killed                  minicom -b 115200 -D /dev/ttyACM0 -C /home/fsnk/scripts/serial-com/output.txt -S /home/fsnk/scripts/serial-com/serial -o
wait another 5s

Finished: SUCCESS
```

After the message `Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys` i would expect it to login to the board (no password, only root user) and run `systemctl is-system-running --wait`. All the output must be on output.txt

Again, this works just as expected when run manually or trigerred from my machine via SSH, but when trigered from Jenkins (Added a build step `execute shell` which tries to SSH and launch the script) it doesnt work.

At this point i feel like its a minicom issue, in that case, i welcome any solution with `screen`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because the killall causes minicom to return an error code to the operating system, which Jenkins evaluates and so considers it a failure. You could add a try/catch block to mark the build unstable or success if that is the cause.

Comment: i know nothing about jenkins but if you are suggesting a solution, consider adding some code.